# Initializer list for dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

It is possible to give an initializer list to the definition of a static array. Example:

```
int main()
{
  int int_static[2] = {1,2};
}
```

Is a similar initializer list possible for a dynamic array?

```
int main()
{
  int* int_ptr = new int[2];
}
```

This is closer to what I am trying to do:

```
struct foo
{
  foo(){}
  foo(void * ptr): ptr_(ptr) {}
  void * ptr_;
};

int main()
{
  foo* foo_ptr = new foo[10];
}
```

At initialization time not the default constructor should be called, but foo:foo(void*).

The point of having a static initializer list for a dynamic array might come handy in the case of Just-In-Time compilation for accelerator cores which do have only a limited amount of stack available, but at the same time you construct your objects with a (accelerator compile time = host run time) static initializer list.

I assume not (since this would require the compiler to generate additional code, namely to copy the values of the arguments to the heap location). I think c++0x supports some of this, but I cannot use it. 
Right now I could use such a construct. Maybe someone knows a trick..

Best!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.

I think C++ doesn't allow this because allowing such thing doesn't add any *nice-to-have* feature to the language. In other words, what would be the point of *dynamic* array if you use a *static* initializer to initialize it?

The point of dynamic array is to create an array of size `N` which is *known* at runtime, depending on the actual need. That is, the code

```
int *p = new int[2];
```

makes less sense to me than the following:

```
int *p = new int[N]; //N is known at runtime
```

If that is so, then how can you provide the number of elements in the *static* initializer because `N` isn't known until runtime?

Lets assume that you're allowed to write this:

```
int *p = new int[2] {10,20}; //pretend this!
```

But what big advantage are you getting by writing this? Nothing. Its *almost* same as:

```
int a[] = {10,20};
```

The real advantage would be when you're allowed to write that for arrays of `N` elements. But then the problem is this:

```
 int *p = new int[N] {10,20, ... /*Oops, no idea how far we can go? N is not known!*/ };
```

Comment: For the record, "dynamic" does not mean "variable-length".  It is indeed a "nice-to-have feature" to be able to create a new dynamic object and initialize it to known initial contents.  That's precisely what constructors do for class and struct type objects.

Comment: To clarify, 'dynamic' in C++ means allocated on the heap instead of the stack. I use both memory stores extensively, so having initializer lists work for both would be extremely convenient. As is, in many cases when I want to create a array list on the heap I have to resort to objects (like std::vector) instead of plain arrays because, as @MikeHousky says, C++ only supports initializing objects on the heap at the moment, not arrays. No techincal or performance issue here - just a limitation of C++.

Answer (score 23):

At the time the OP posted this question, C++11 support may not have been very prevalent yet, which is why the accepted answer says this is not possible. However, initializing a dynamic array with an explicit initializer list should now be supported in all major C++ compilers.

The syntax `new int[3] {1, 2, 3}` was standardized in C++11. Quoting the *[new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Construction)* page on cppreference.com:

> The object created by a new-expression is initialized according to the following rules:
>   ...
>   If *type* is an array type, an array of objects is initialized:
>   ...
>   If *initializer* is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the array is aggregate-initialized. (since C++11)

So, given the OP's example, the following is perfectly legal when using C++11 or newer:

```
foo * foo_array = new foo[2] { nullptr, nullptr };
```

Note that by providing pointers in the initializer list, we're actually coaxing the compiler to apply the `foo(void * ptr)` constructor (rather than the default constructor), which was the desired behavior.

Comment: This is only possible if the size of foo_array is a compile-time constant, even in C++11 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will have to create the elements dynamically.

Alternatively, you can use a local array and copy its elements over those of the dynamically allocated array:

```
int main() {
   int _detail[] = { 1, 2 };
   int * ptr = new int[2];
   std::copy( _detail, _detail+(sizeof detail / sizeof *detail), ptr );
   delete [] ptr;
}
```

In the limited version of setting all elements to 0, you can use an extra pair of parenthesis in the `new` call:

```
int * ptr = new int[2]();  // will value initialize all elements
```

But you seem to be looking for a different thing.

Comment: The punctuation in your first sentence was a little misleading; have "fixed". Rollback if you disagree.

Comment: I am looking exactly for a way to call the constructor of each element that is dynamically allocated (of course its not just an "int"). But its not the standard constructor that has to be called. It must take 1 arg and the lvalue for that argument is for each element different.

Comment: shouldn't _detail be an int*?

Comment: Thanks to Tomalak and James for fixing the answer.

Comment: The next set of questions are about the actual requirements (that again, like most others, you have not provided): why does it have to be dynamically allocated? why can you not use `std::vector`? do you control both allocation an deallocation?

Answer (score 0):

The initializer data must be somewhere anyway. Simply name it.

E.g.,

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <algorithm>        // std::copy
#include <vector>

typedef ptrdiff_t   Size;

template< class Type, Size n >
Size countOf( Type (&)[n] ) { return n; }

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    static int const    initData[]  = {1,2};
    static Size const   n           = countOf( initData );

    // Initialization of a dynamically allocated array:
    int*        pArray  = new int[n];
    copy( initData, initData + n, pArray );

    // Initialization of a vector:
    vector<int> v( initData, initData + n );
}
```

**EDIT**: fixed a thinko in above code. I hastened to add example on request. So what I put did erroneously use return value from `std::copy`.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: This isn't particularly clear.  Could you give an illustrative example?

Comment: @Oli, I guess he refers to something similar to the solution that I suggest in my answer, just ignoring the gory details of the needed copy.

Comment: However, I seem to be "getting" this about SO that in order for answer to be grokked, it needs to be fleshed out with very detailed example, giving the man a fish. I generally don't think to do that because it's the thing to absolutely not do in order to help someone. Even though it is the thing to do in order to get upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're real class is more complex than an int, and constructed from differing values, it's complicated.
A vector can be constructed with iterators if you have an existing array/vector with the correct values to default from, or you have to use placement new.

```
//vector
int main()
{
  int int_static[2] = {1,2};
  std::vector<int> int_dynamic(int_static, int_static+2);
  //this is what everyone else is saying.  For good reason.
}
//placement new
int function_that_returns_constructed_from_values() {
    return rand();
}
int main() 
{
    int count = 2;
    char *char_dynamic = new char[count * sizeof(int)];
    int *int_dynamic = char_dynamic;
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
        new(int_dynamic+i)int(function_that_returns_constructed_from_values());
    //stuff
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
        (int_dynamic+i)->~int(); //obviously not really int
    delete []char_dynamic;
}
```

Obviously, the vector is the preferred way to do this.