# Dynamic array in a class in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, array-initialization

I have a dynamic array, for which I allocate memory with a function inside my class:

```
double *val;
int n; // dimension

void alloc (int nn) { // memory allocation for vector
    n = nn;
    val = new double[n];
}
```

but when I try to put the data in it in main I have the following problem:

When I type:

```
a.val[3] = {1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0};
```

I get the following very ambiguous errors:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
syntax error : '{'
```

But when I type:

```
a.val[1]=1.0;
a.val[2]=1.0;
a.val[3]=1.0;
```

it works just fine. Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: array of double. both shoud do the same, shoudn't they? I know the  a.val[3] = {1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0}; version is generally correct..

Answer (score 3):

You can only initialize an array in that way:

```
double a[3] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
```

Your alternatives are:

```
void alloc (int nn) { // memory allocation for vector
    n = nn;
    val = new double[n];

    // one option is:
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        val[i] = 1.0;
    }    

    // or you can also do: (thanks to Benjamin)
    std::fill_n(val, n, 1.0);

    // or:
    std::fill(val, val + n, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: the array is initialized inside the class, i've edited my answer to show that.

Comment: @System as i said in my answer, the array is already initialized when you allocated the memory for it in, `val = new double[n];`

Comment: @System see this, [Initializer list for dynamic arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124899/initializer-list-for-dynamic-arrays)

Comment: Not the only option. There's [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks! I added that alternatives to the answer.

Comment: @alfonso I made an edit to your answer. The two functions, `fill` and `fill_n` are templated functions, which means they can detect the type of the elements at compile-time. Because of this you only need to pass the number of elements `n`, not the memory they occupy `n * sizeof(double)`. The same goes for pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

`a.val[3] = {1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0};`

this only works for initialization.

In your case, you have first allocated the space dynamically during which the the initialization takes place.

This will work

```
float val[3]={1.0,1.0,1.0};
```

Comment: but I want the vector to be linked with a specific object, in this case a. How do I do that?

Comment: what you said indeed works, the result I get for my program is correct but when I print a.val[1] for example I get a very big (and wrong) number.

Answer (score 0):

you may only use {data} for initilizing 
but if you still want to use this for setting multiple values try this:

```
double values[3] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
memcpy(&(a.val), &values, sizeof(values));
```