# extended initializer lists only available with

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm very new to C++ and I'm having trouble reading my errors I was able to eliminate most of them but I'm down to a few and I'm request help on them please.

Here is the program

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int *bN = new int[9];
 string bankNum;
 int *number = new int[9];
 int total, remain;
 int *multi = new int{7,3,9,7,3,9,7,3};
 cout<<"Please enter the bank number located at the bottom of the check"<<endl;
 cin>>bankNum;
 for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  bN[i]= (bankNum[i]-48);
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < 8;i++){
  cout<<bN[i];
 }
 cout<<endl;
 for(int i = 0; i < 8;i++){
  cout<<multi[i];
 }
 cout<<endl;
 for(int i = 0; i < 8;i++){
  bN[i] = bN[i] * multi[i];
  cout<< bN[i];
 }
 cout<<endl;
 for(int i = 0; i < 8;i++){
  total += bN[i]
  cout<<total;
 }
 cout<<endl;
 remain = total % 10;
 if(remain == (bankNum[9] - 48)){
  cout<<"The Number is valad"<<endl;
  cout<<remain<<endl;
 }
}
```

and the errors

```
wm018@cs:~$ c++ bankNum.cpp
bankNum.cpp: In function âint main()â:
bankNum.cpp:9:19: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
bankNum.cpp:9:38: error: cannot convert â<brace-enclosed initializer list>â to âintâ in initialization
bankNum.cpp:30:3: error: expected â;â before âcoutâ
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This style of initialisation, using braces:

```
int *multi = new int{7,3,9,7,3,9,7,3};
```

was introduced to the language in 2011. Older compilers don't support it; some newer ones (like yours) only support it if you tell them; for your compiler:

```
c++ -std=c++0x bankNum.cpp
```

However, this form of initialisation still isn't valid for arrays created with `new`. Since it's small and only used locally, you could declare a local array; this doesn't need C++11 support:

```
int multi[] = {7,3,9,7,3,9,7,3};
```

This also has the advantage of fixing the memory leak - if you use `new` to allocate memory, then you should free it with `delete` when you've finished with it.

If you did need dynamic allocation, you should use `std::vector` to allocate and free the memory for you:

```
std::vector<int> multi {7,3,9,7,3,9,7,3};
```

Beware that your version of GCC is quite old, and has incomplete support for C++11.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124899/initializer-list-for-dynamic-arrays

Comment: Incomplete and buggy, even the latest builds still sometimes miss conformance on the standard when you try to push harder on c++11 new language features… Never trust the result of a single compiler to state that a code is well formed or not.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Fair enough; I rarely use `new` directly, and only checked the syntax with one compiler. The answer should be more correct now.

Comment: `int *multi = new int{7,3,9,7,3,9,7,3};' is not what you expect: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int’ in initialization

Comment: @DieterLücking: Indeed; which is why I corrected the answer to say "this form of initialisation still isn't valid" and suggested valid alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

errors-:

1)there is an syntactical error in your 5th for loop which is you forgot to put ; after ***total+=b[N]***

2)since your array multi is small and the value and size is  predefined then initialize it with ***int multi[] = {7,3,9,7,3,9,7,3};*** this way

suggestions to improve programme efficiency-:
1)instead of defining ***i*** variable ***5*** times for each ***for*** loop will give  ***error in C/C++***  so in order to avoid it you can declare i as a global variable

Comment: Please avoid using bold text for the code, try using backticks `

Comment: Welcome Prakhar gupta! As @PanwenWang says, please consider using backtics instead of bold text for code. Also it will be useful to use markdown numbered lists to improve the formatting of your answer.