# warning: extended initializer lists only available with std c++ 11

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Getting warning while using below code:

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with std c++ 11

```
struct test{
 int a;
 int b;
};

//Previously const test atest[] = { {2,3} {4,5} };
const test atest[] = { {2,3} , {4,5} };
```

How can I remove this? I tried with [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579654/extended-initializer-lists-only-available-with), but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you intentionally tag this as c?

Comment: I changed it to C++ now..

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version? What options are you using? I can't reproduce this for your code, are you sure that's what you're compiling? If you are trying to use C++11 then you need to use `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

Comment: What does the compiler generate when you use `const test atest[] = {2,3,4,5};`?

Comment: I am using MGC 1.8 compiler. Mentor Graphics Compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const test atest[] = { {2,3}, {4,5} };
```

You forget the comma, and in C you need the `struct` keyword if `test` is not typedefed:

```
const struct test atest[] = { {2,3}, {4,5} };
```

Comment: I tried with solution you suggested but it is giving me same compiler warning.

Comment: http://ideone.com/54yjIG