# How to fix warning: extended initializer lists?

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281065/warning-extended-initializer-lists-only-available-with-std-c-11) and elsewhere but none that fix this issue.

gcc 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 produces the following warning

> extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or
>   -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

for the following code

```
// Mutex.h
class CMutex
{
    ...
private:
    pthread_mutex_t m_plock;
};

// Mutex.cpp
CMutex::CMutex()
{
    m_plock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
}
```

How is this warning best resolved?

Comment: By adding `-std=c++0x` option as the message suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC just wants you to know that you're using C++11 features (in case you didn't intend to), even if it allows them by default. To disable the warning just add the switch that it is suggesting, i.e. `-std=c++0x` to let it know this is indeed your intention.