# How to iterate through a variadic template to fill a POD array

Tags: c++

How can I summarize the arguments of my variadic template method in a POD array (c array)? At the moment I don`t know to iterate over the arguments...

```
enum class ParamId {kTyp1, kTyp2, kTyp3};

struct Params
{
   ParamId* ids; 
   int32 count; 
};

template <typename... Args>
Params add (const ParamId& value, Args&&... values)
{
   constexpr int32 count = sizeof... (Args); 
   ParamId* params = new ParamId[count];

   for(int32 i=0; i<count; i++)
   {
     params[i] = ????
   }

    return Params {params, count};
}
```

EDIT: 
Instead of using a for loop I use a reverse iteration approach. Unfortunately I need another method for this. Maybe there`s a better approach. 
And I add the first argument to my list.

```
enum class ParamId {kTyp1, kTyp2, kTyp3};

struct Params
{
   ParamId* ids; 
   int32 count; 
};

template <typename... Args>
Params add (ParamId value, Args&&... values)
{
   constexpr int32 count = 1 + sizeof... (Args); 
   ParamId params [count];

    int32 num = 0;
    params[num] = value;
    iterate(&params[0], num++, values...); 

    return Params {params, count};
}

template <typename... Args>
void iterate (ParamId* params, int32 num, ParamId value, Args&&... values)
{
    params[num] = value;
    iterate(params, num++, values...); 
}

void iterate (ParamId* params, int32 num) {}
```

Comment: Iterating over a parameter pack usually means using recursion instead of loops.

Comment: can you use a `initializer_list` instead of the variadic template?

Comment: btw is it on purpose that you dont use the first parameter `value`?

Comment: Although the way you have it is ok, the `value` parameter would better be passed by value, not as a const reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this<sup>1</sup>:

```
constexpr std::size_t count = 1 + sizeof... (Args); 
ParamId* params = new ParamId[count] { value, values... };
```

Assuming you want to put `value` as the first element, which you say in the question but is not what the code does.

But in my opinion, you would be better off using `std::vector` directlry.

<sub><sup>1</sup> See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37913974/2666289) for reference.</sub>