# Dynamic array initialization behavior of msvc differs from gcc and clang

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, c++17

Given the type

```
struct S
{
    int x;
};
```

and two functions

```
S* f()
{
    const auto x = new S[1] { { 42 } };
    return x;
}

S* g() 
{
    const auto x = new S[1];
    x[0] = {42};
    return x;
}
```

one would think that `f` and `g` behave identical. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37913974/6205379) `f` should perform an aggregate initialization on `x` which would result in identical behavior. Looking at the assembly of clang and gcc this seems to be true and both `f` and `g` generate the exact same assembly.

However, msvc doesn't feel like doing it, I guess. The assembly of msvc for `g` is similar to clang and gcc, but for `f` it just seems to ignore the initializer altogether:

```
S * f(void) PROC                                    ; f, COMDAT
        mov     ecx, 4
        jmp     void * operator new[](unsigned __int64)                     ; operator new[]
S * f(void) ENDP                                    ; f

S * g(void) PROC                                    ; g, COMDAT
$LN4:
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        mov     ecx, 4
        call    void * operator new[](unsigned __int64)               ; operator new[]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 42                 ; 0000002aH
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        ret     0
S * g(void) ENDP                                    ; g
```

Curiously, if we replace `S` with `int` msvc performs the initialization, but also adds some additional instructions (which I don't understand, maybe someone can shine a light on that as well).

```
int * f(void) PROC                                 ; f, COMDAT
$LN6:
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        mov     ecx, 4
        call    void * operator new[](unsigned __int64)               ; operator new[]
        test    rax, rax
        je      SHORT $LN3@f
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 42                 ; 0000002aH
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        ret     0
$LN3@f:
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        ret     0
int * f(void) ENDP                                 ; f
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gpc-Dq) is a full example.

What is the standard conforming behavior in this case? And what are those additional assembly instructions in `f` doing (if we replace `S` with `int`)?

### Edit

Bug has been reported and can be tracked [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/816869/aggregate-initialization-is-not-performed-on-dynam.html).

Comment: For the additional instructions added, I'm not sure why it is changing the stack pointer, which seems rather useless; but the `test rax,rax; je SHORT $LN3@f` is to ensure it doesn't try to initialize in the case when `new[]` fails.

Comment: Looks like `msvc` bug. You should send them a feedback.