# Initialise a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory

I know for static arrays whose memory allocation is done on the stack are initialized by
`int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5}`. I want to know how do you initialize a dynamically allocated array in C++.
The following method seems wrong.
`int *array = new int[5]; array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124899/initializer-list-for-dynamic-arrays

Comment: The best way to do this is to use a vector and initialize it. `vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5}`